# CKSubscription to creatorUserRecordID never arrives

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, cloudkit, cksubscription

I create CKSubscription using the following code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(creatorUserRecordID == %@)", self.myRecordId];

CKSubscription *subscription2 = [[CKSubscription alloc]
                                initWithRecordType:@"Message"
                                predicate:predicate2
                                options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation];
```

where self.myRecordId is CKRecordID of the current logged user. I do this because I would like to receive notification when I create a new object (of type Message) but the problem is that notification never arrives. Anyone has idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You should complete the missing steps described in the [Quick Start Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH8-SW1) namely set the notification object, assign it to the subscription, and assign the subscription to the public database:

[image: cksubscriptions]

Please note the verification steps on the original source.